Zsh terminal outputs error when trying to link libraries installed with homebrew
I'm trying to create my own game engine in rust using sdl2 and opengl to create a graphics engine and the ecs or entity-component-system software architectural pattern for game logic seeing as rust is somewhat of a data oriented programming language. The current problem i'm running into as of right now is using the sdl2 crate to open a window seeing as this specific crate relies on the sdl2 library. A library which can be installed on a macbook using the homebrew package manager.
brew --install sdl2

the above terminal command uses homebrew to install the sdl2 library
As stated on the official sdl2 crate github page under the macos section more recent versions of hombrew place installed libraries into the /opt/homebrew/lib directory whereas older versions place installed libraries into the /usr/local/lib directory. And in order to make linking installed libraries easier we need to add the following line of code to the zsh environment file, a hidden file found in the home directory.
export LIBRARY_PATH="$LIBRARY_PATH:$(brew --prefix)/lib"

the above code can be placed into the ~/.zshenv file
In order to do this open a new terminal and type the following commands
cd ~
open .zshenv

the first line of the above code navigates to the home directory and the second opens the .zshenv file in text edit
Now you would think this would work yet it doesn't and we can see this right away if we open a new terminal. Immediately we get an error which prevents this from linking the sdl2 library to the sdl2 crate.
.zshenv:2: command not found: brew
So my question to anyone reading this post is how would I go about solving this? Any help is greatly appreciated.
I've tried a bunch of things and have spent an ungodly amount of time on just this issue. The one bandaid solution i've found to this problem is to just directly declare the path as such.
export LIBRARY_PATH="$LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/homebrew/lib"

the above code should be placed into the ~/.zshenv file replacing the previous line of code we added
Sure it works but is not the solution I am looking for. :)

The error is telling you that it couldn't find brew in your path, where in your .zshenv have you placed the line? Before or after adding Homebrew's binary to your $PATH?

Unless i'm mistaken the path to homebrews binary is defined before the line of code. Seeing as when you install homebrew onto your system it makes you run three commands one of which defines the path to the homebrew binary in another hidden file called .zprofile or you can manually add the path into another hidden file .zshrc which you have to create yourself. And in my research these files are both were you should define the path and will run before the .zshenv hidden file.
